# How do I hide/show pictuers in an interactive story

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have to make an interactive story using jQuery, HTML, and CSS. I want to make the character picture appear in the game. When the mage character is talking, I want his pic to appear. When you click on him three times, he dies and the picture will hide. This is all based on the progression of #speech if statement. After the mage dies, he will drop a book which you have to pick up to preceed to the next page.

```
$(document).ready(function() { // do not delete this line
  var progress = 0;
  var txt;

  function eventHandler() {
    if (progress == 0) {
      txt = "MAGE: Ah you must be after this book.";
      //$('#speech').prepend('<img id="img" src="mage.png" />')       //old  code to make image appear
      //$('#speech').css('background-image', 'url("mage.png")')       // new code but makes image appear in speech box (want it appear behind)

      $('#mage').show
    }

    if (progress == 1) {
      txt = "PLAYER: give it back and i might spare you!";
    }

    if (progress == 2) {
      txt = "MAGE: Nah i think i will hold onto it for a while, you will have to take it from my cold dead hands!";
    }

    if (progress == 3) {
      txt = "PLAYER: That can be arranged.";
      //$('#mage').on('click', function(){
      //$('#mage').hide(4000, function(){
      //alert('toggled');
      //}});
    }

    if (progress == 4) {
      txt = "MAGE: Ah damn just take it leave me be!";
      $('#speech').css('background-image', '')
    }

    if (progress == 5) {
      txt = "PLAYER: I'll take that.";
    }

    if (progress == 6) {
      txt = "PLAYER: I should report back to the king at once.";
    }

    progress++;
    $('#speech').html(txt);
    //$('#text').html(txt)
  }

  $('#speech').click(eventHandler);
}); // do not delete this line
#stage1 {
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(home.jpg);
}

#speech {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#btn {
  position: relative;
  display: show;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-top: 350px;
}

#stage2 {
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(castle.jpg);
}

#stage3 {
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(dungeon.jpg);
}

#stage4 {
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(entrance.jpg);
}

#stage5 {
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(path.jpeg)
}

#stage6 {
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(forest.jpg)
}

#mage {
  display: none;
}

#book {
  display: none;
}

#stage7 {
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(castle.jpg);
}

#stage8 {
  width: 900px;
  height: 505px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(entrance.jpg);
}
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MMCC3045</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stage6">
    <a href="page7.html"><button id="btn">to castle</button>    </a>
    <!--<div id="speech"><span id="text" style="z-index: 1">PLAYER: Ok so in the forest. seem quiet best look around for him.</span></div> new code making img appear in speech not behind -->
    <div id="speech">PLAYER: Ok so in the forest. seem quiet best look around for him.</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="mage.png" id="mage" alt="mage" width="500" height="500">
    <img src="book.png" id="book" alt="book" width="500" height="500">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestions. i added $('#mage').hide(); into if(progress == 3) at the end of the statement and it breaks the speech tree. i want the mage to appear after the first dialog by the player and the mage img become hidden when on clicked 3 times. then a book will appear of which the player will need to pick up to proceed to next stage (the button to the next scene being hidden if not picked up book

Comment: `$('#mage').show`... looks like you already know how to show/hide. What is your question?

Comment: thr code breaks when i use that on the if statement. ". i want the mage to appear after the first dialog by the player and the mage img become hidden when on clicked 3 times. then a book will appear of which the player will need to pick up to proceed to next stage (the button to the next scene being hidden if not picked up book '